# Der Unterschied zwischen «im Moment», «im Augenblick» und «vorerst»

Tags: grammar, adverb

> Im Moment bin ich im Park und trainiere meine Arme mit meinem Freund
>   Johan.
>
> Im Augenblick bin ich im Park und trainiere meine Arme mit meinem
>   Freund Johan.
>
> Vorerst bin ich im Park und trainiere meine Arme mit meinem Freund
>   Johan.

Kann man sie austauschbar verwenden? Haben sie einen großen Unterschied in diesem Zusammenhang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Vorerst* is the odd one out. Die anderen beiden sind Synonyme und können nach belieben ausgetauscht werden.

*Vorerst* hingegen bedeutet *vorläufig*, *erst einmal*. Es bedeutet, dass die Aussage solange wahr ist, bis etwas anderes bestimmt wird.
Aktuell hört man diese Wörter häufig im Kontext der Europameisterschaft. Spieler werden vorläufig zum EM-Kader gewählt. Sie sind also vorerst dabei. Dies kann (und wird) sich aber noch ändern.

*Im Augenblick* und *Im Moment* beziehen sich beide auf *genau jetzt*.

Letztlich sind alle drei Sätze richtig, aber der dritte Satz hat eine leicht andere Aussage als die ersten beiden.